# Setting SKEmitterNode's 'targetNode' causes strange 'zPosition' behavior

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

While trying to implement a *trail-of-particles* effect in one of my SpriteKit games, I've encountered something strange: when setting an `SKEmitterNode`'s `targetNode` to `self.scene`, the particles become no longer visible.

What's actually happening is this: **The particles are rendering either a) *in front of*, or b) *behind* a background image `SKSpriteNode` depending on whether or not `targetNode` is set**. You can see this for yourself by giving the background node some alpha transparency, which allows you to see the particles *through* the background.

Setting the relevant `zPosition`'s on the emitter node and its parent does not solve the problem -- the particles render behind the background node regardless of `zPosition` (assuming that the background node's `zPosition` is set).

I've trimmed it down to a minimal reproducible example; if you plug this `GameScene` into a fresh SpriteKit project, you should see the behavior I'm talking about.

For the background image, just use any opaque image. For the particle file, just use the standard "Smoke" template.

Note: The particles render correctly on the Simulator, so use a real device.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        let screen = UIScreen.main.bounds
        
        self.scene?.backgroundColor = .white
        
        self.scaleMode = .resizeFill
        self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
        
        let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "testBackground")
        let parent = SKSpriteNode()
        let emitter = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "SmokeParticles")
        
        background.size = CGSize(width: screen.width, height: screen.height)
        background.position = CGPoint(x: screen.width*0.5, y: screen.height*0.5)
        background.zPosition = 0.5 //Giving the background a zPosition is necessary to reproduce the problem.
        //background.alpha = 0.7 //Add this line to see that the particles are BEHIND the background when 'targetNode' is set.
        
        parent.size = CGSize(width: 50.0, height: 50.0)
        parent.position = background.position
        parent.zPosition = 5.0
        
        if let emitter = emitter {
            emitter.zPosition = 5.0 //I would think this should solve the problem, but it doesn't
            emitter.targetNode = self.scene //Comment or uncomment this line to toggle the problem on/off.
            parent.addChild(emitter)
        }
        
        addChild(background)
        
        addChild(parent)
    }
    

    func touchDown(atPoint pos: CGPoint) {

    }

    func touchMoved(toPoint pos : CGPoint) {
    }

    func touchUp(atPoint pos : CGPoint) {
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for t in touches { self.touchDown(atPoint: t.location(in: self)) }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for t in touches { self.touchMoved(toPoint: t.location(in: self)) }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for t in touches { self.touchUp(atPoint: t.location(in: self)) }
    }

    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for t in touches { self.touchUp(atPoint: t.location(in: self)) }
    }


    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        
    }
    
}
```

**Question:** Is this a bug, or some godforsaken feature? Are you seeing this same behavior?

Comment: What is the sense to assign targetNode to SKScene? Must be a SKNode child of the scene

Comment: Apple's documentation recommends assigning `targetNode` to an `SKScene` both here -> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skemitternode/changing_the_location_of_particles_in_your_scene ... and here -> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skemitternode/1398012-targetnode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this problem by using the `SKEmitterNode`'s `particleZPosition` property.